# Stuck in opening serial port

Tags: c, freeze, xbee

I have this code for a comunication between pc-arduino with xbee.
The problem is that when I execute this, the program seems to be freezed and doesn't receive nothing from arduino, I don't know why is this happening, but one time the program was showing in the 'terminal' the message that I want to show to see if the communication is happening: 'line:....'
But now isn't communicating.

Are any errors in the code, or why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>      // standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <math.h>
#define XBEE "/dev/ttyUSB0"
#define BAUDRATE B9600

double average(int data[],int elem);
double desviation(double m, int data[],int elem);
void  normalize(double data[],int elem);
void store(double data[],int ex);
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{   
    struct termios tio;
    struct termios stdio;
    struct termios old_stdio;
    struct termios options;
    int data[262142];
    int tty_fd = open(XBEE , O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    
    again:
    cfsetospeed(&tio,BAUDRATE);    
    cfsetispeed(&tio,BAUDRATE);            // baudrate is declarated above
    tcsetattr(tty_fd,TCSANOW,&tio);

    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    
 //   write(tty_fd,&c,'1');
    char o='o';
    char a='a';
    FILE *f; 
    char line[100];
    f = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB0", "r+");
    while(line[0]!='o'){
        fgets(line,10,f);
        printf("line: %s\n",line);
    }
    while(line[0]=='o'){
        fputc(a,f);
        fgets(line,10,f);
        printf("line: %s\n",line);
    }
        int count=0;
        int pos=0;
        //----------------------
        while(1){
            printf("dentro: %c\n",line[0]);
            int num;
            char number[3];     
            if(line[0]!=' '){
                number[count]=line[0];
                if(count>3){
                    count=0;
                }
                else{
                count=count+1;
                }
            }
            if(line[0]==' '){
                count=0;
                sscanf(number,"%d",&num);
                printf("%d\n",num);
                data[pos]=num;
            }
            
            if(line[0]=='\n'){
                printf("\n\nAll the data have been received");
                double av=average(data,262142);
                double desv=desviation(av,data,262142);

                double data2[262142];
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
                {
                    data2[i]=(data[i]-av)/desv;
                }
                normalize(data2,262142);
                char ex;
                int aux;
                printf("It was steps? y/n\n");
                scanf ("%c",&ex);
                if(ex=='y'){
                    aux=1;
                    }
                else{
                    aux=0;
                }
                store(data2,aux);
                fputc(o,f);
                line[0]='0';
                while(line[0]!='o'){
                    fgets(line,10,f);       
                }
                break;
            }
            
            write(tty_fd,&o,1);
            line[0]='0';

            while(line[0]!='o'){
                fgets(line,10,f);       
            }
            line[0]='x';
            while(line[0]=='x'){
                fgets(line,10,f);
            }

        }
    goto again;
    close(tty_fd);
    tcsetattr(STDOUT_FILENO,TCSANOW,&old_stdio);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

postdata: I can't use the API mode, need to do this on c.

**Update**

I have done all you have said to me. Still not working, the debugger is stuck in the first fgets (line 30).

```
#include <stdio.h>      // standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <math.h>
#define XBEE "/dev/ttyUSB0"
#define BAUDRATE B9600

double average(int data[],int elem);
double desviation(double m, int data[],int elem);
void  normalize(double data[],int elem);
void store(double data[],int ex);
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    int data[262142];
    char o='o';
    char a='a';
    char line[100];
    FILE *f;

    again:
    f = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB0", "r+");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening the port\n");
    }

    while(line[0]!='o'){
        fgets(line,10,f);
        printf("line: %s\n",line);
    }
    while(line[0]=='o'){
        fputc(a,f);
        fgets(line,10,f);
        printf("line: %s\n",line);
    }
        int count=0;
        int pos=0;
        //----------------------
        while(1){
            printf("dentro: %c\n",line[0]);
            int num;
            char number[3];
            if(line[0]!=' '){
                number[count]=line[0];
                if(count>3){
                    count=0;
                }
                else{
                count=count+1;
                }
            }
            if(line[0]==' '){
                count=0;
                sscanf(number,"%d",&num);
                printf("%d\n",num);
                data[pos]=num;
            }

            if(line[0]=='\n'){
                printf("\n\nAll the data have been received");
                double av=average(data,262142);
                double desv=desviation(av,data,262142);

                double data2[262142];
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
                {
                    data2[i]=(data[i]-av)/desv;
                }
                normalize(data2,262142);
                char ex;
                int aux;
                printf("It was steps? y/n\n");
                scanf ("%c",&ex);
                if(ex=='y'){
                    aux=1;
                    }
                else{
                    aux=0;
                }
                store(data2,aux);
                fputc(o,f);
                line[0]='0';
                while(line[0]!='o'){
                    fgets(line,10,f);
                }
                break;
            }

            fputc(o,f);
            line[0]='0';

            while(line[0]!='o'){
                fgets(line,10,f);
            }
            line[0]='x';
            while(line[0]=='x'){
                fgets(line,10,f);
            }

        }
    goto again;
    fclose(f);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


double average(int data[],int elem){
    int i=0;
    int sum=0;
    for (i = 0; i < elem; i++){
       sum+=data[i];
    }
    return sum/elem;
}

double desviation(double m, int data[],int elem){
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    double dif=0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < elem; i++){
            dif=pow(data[i]-m,2);

    }

    return sqrt(dif/(18000-1));
}

void normalize(double data[],int elem){

    int i,j;
    double biggest;
    double lowest;
    double aux;
    biggest = 0.0;
    lowest = 9999999999999999.999;
    for (i = 0; i < elem; i++){
            if(data[i]>biggest){
                biggest=data[i];
            }
            if(data[i]<lowest){
                lowest=data[i];
            }
    }
    if (abs(biggest)>abs(lowest)){
        aux=abs(biggest);}
    else{
        aux=abs(lowest);}
    for (i = 0; i < elem; i++){
            data[i]=data[i]/aux;
        }
}

void store(double data[],int ex){
    FILE *out;
    out=fopen("training.data","r");
    char line[262142];
    fgets(line,262142,out);
    char *values;
    values=strtok(line," ");
    int val;
    sscanf(&values[0],"%d",&val);
    FILE *out2;
    out2=fopen("trainingAux.data","w");
    fprintf(out2,"%d 262142 1\n",val+1);
    while(fgets(line,262142,out)!=NULL){
        fprintf(out2,"%s",line);
    }
    int i = 0;
    for(i;i<262141;i++){
        fprintf(out2,"%lf ", data[i]);
    }
    fprintf(out2,"%lf\n", data[i+1]);
    fprintf(out2,"%d\n",ex);
    fclose(out2);
    fclose(out);
    out=fopen("training.data","w");
    out2=fopen("trainingAux.data","r");
    while(fgets(line,262142,out2)!=NULL){
        fprintf(out,"%s",line);
    }
    fclose(out);
    fclose(out2);
}
```

Comment: First, 'while(line[0]!='o'){' - why are you testing the content of a buffer that is not initialized or loaded at that point?

Comment: When you ran it under your debugger, what line did it get stuck on?  Is it looping or blocked?  What protocol are you using for the comms? You know all this stuff, we don't.  If you don't help us, we can't help you.

Comment: Well, the completely lack of any error checking ensures that you'll never be able to diagnose an error.

Comment: Martin James, I'm not using any protocol, im just making a kind of ack with sending 'o' after a data, both xbees are in transparent mode. I'm not using debugger right now, I'm only compiling it on terminal of ubuntu, let me try one debugger and I will update it, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to figure out what's happening when communicating via serial.
  First of all, why are you using 'fopen' right after using 'open' to the same path (/dev/ttyUSB0)?
  When you use a handle to estabilish communication like 'tty_fd' you have to be sure that this handle was created sucessfully, you can try:

`if ( (tty_fd = open(XBEE , O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY)) == -1 ){
   IfTraceAvaliable("Error while opening");
   return -1;
}`

In addition, you may be trying to set some attributes on termios struct, like:

`options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;`

But after it, you aren't applying it to your connection, like:
`ioctl(tty_fd, TCSETA, &options);`

Remember you can also test ioctl == 0, if its not equal, than it means you couldn't set it properly.

[Edit]
Since you're using open(), you can use read() function to retrieve the answer from arduino, instead of using fgets or fread, that can be an alternative.

Comment: Oh, i think that i had to have the open too, i prefer the fopen, it is easier to use, thank you for your comment!